# How Can I make an excel column of Hyperlinks open in NON default browser

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-office-2007

I have a ms excel 2007 worksheet with a column (A) of hyperlinks using the excel function in this way `=HYPERLINK(A2,"url"`.

How Can I make (if this is possible) open all cels on that column in the NON default browser?

Comment: Short answer is no you cannot

Answer (score 2):

If you enter the path of the browser with the exe file and put the URL after, it will open using that browser.

For example

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://superuser.com/questions/1079979/how-can-i-make-an-excel-column-of-hyperlinks-open-in-non-default-browser
```

Unfortunately you can not use this in Excels `Hyperlink` function, so we need a workaround.

One solution would be, to create a batch file and set the hyperlink to run that batch file. All you need to do is copy the code into a text file, and save it as .bat

---

Another solution is using VBA.
Press alt + F11, and paste the following code into "ThisWorkbook".

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

If Target.Name = "asd" Then 'Or you can identify a cell using it's range instead of its name If Target.Range.Address = "$A$1" Then

Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe http://superuser.com/questions/1079979/how-can-i-make-an-excel-column-of-hyperlinks-open-in-non-default-browser")
End If

End Sub
```

Than you have to make a hyperlink out of the cell by right click, hyperlink, select *place in this document*, than ok.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little old but it is referenced in a newer, similar question so I am adding an updated answer. In my example my spreadsheet has three columns, **`DATE, URL, OTHER_INFO`** and the **URL** column has the links.

With the excellent [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.0.1) module this becomes pretty easy. From the module, use the [Import-Excel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/tree/master/Examples/Import-Excel) cmdlet to read the spreadsheet into a variable and then use a foreach loop to open each link:

```
$excel = Import-Excel -Path "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Temp\test.xlsx"
$brows = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
foreach ($url in $excel.URL){
    Start-Process -FilePath $brows -ArgumentList $url
    #    Write-Host $brows $url  ## TEST
    }

Start-Process -FilePath $brows -ArgumentList $url
```

This opens each link in a new tab in Edge.

If you are unable to use the ImportExcel module, it is more verbose but you can still [access spreadsheet data using the COM objects](https://lazywinadmin.com/2014/03/powershell-read-excel-file-using-com.html)

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.